# Elasticsearch filter group by using nest c#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using elastic search to get the products grouped by category and perform aggregations on result....
If I use categoryid(numeric) as a field its giving result but when i try to give category name its giving Unsuccessful(400)

Please see the blow code snippet

I am getting document count. Can i get document data from same request?

```
ISearchResponse<Products> results;

        results = _client.Search<Products>(s => s
                    //.Size(int.MaxValue)
                    .Query(q => q
                        .Bool(b => b
                            .Should(
                                bs => bs.Prefix(p => p.cat_name, "heli"),
                                bs => bs.Prefix(p => p.pr_name, "heli")
                                    )
                            )
                        )
                    .Aggregations(a => a
                        .Terms("catname", t => t
                            .Field(f => f.categoryid)
                            .Size(int.MaxValue)
                            .Aggregations(agg => agg
                               .Max("maxprice", av => av.Field(f2 => f2.price))
                               .Average("avgprice", av => av.Field(f3 => f3.price))
                               .Max("maxweidht", av => av.Field(f2 => f2.weight))
                               .Average("avgweight", av => av.Field(f3 => f3.weight))
                               )
                            )
                        )
                    );
```

mapping model:

```
{
  "product_catalog": {
     "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "@timestamp": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "@version": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "cat_name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "categoryid": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "createdon": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "fulldescription": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "height": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "length": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "pr_name": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "price": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "productid": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "shortdescription": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "sku": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "updatedon": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "weight": {
      "type": "float"
    },
    "width": {
      "type": "float"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Can anyone guide how to use category name for grouping.

Comment: Could you share index mapping? Probably field `catname` is of type text in your case and by default, you can't do terms aggs on such fields, but to make sure would be great to see your mapping.

Comment: Thank you @Rob, i have updated mapping in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`catname` field is of type `text` and thus you can't use it by default in aggregations because [`fielddata` is disabled](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) for performance reasons.

Based on your mapping I see you are also indexing `keyword` as well for `catname` so you can use this field.
Just change this part of your term aggregation `.Field(f => f.categoryid)` to
`.Field(f => f.cat_name.Suffix("keyword"))` and you should be good.